# Caused by: java.nio.file.InvalidPathException: Illegal char <:> at index 58: com.example.project.app-mergeDebugResources-32:/values/values.xml

Tags: java, android, xml, gradle, build.gradle

> D:\AndroidStudioProjects\myproject\app\build\intermediates\incremental\debug\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml. Cause: java.nio.file.InvalidPathException: Illegal char <:> at index 58: com.example.myproject.app-mergeDebugResources-32:/values/values.xml). Check logs for more details.

I tried everything but didn't find any solution please help me Guys.
[image]

[image]

Comment: When does this error happen?

Comment: Sorry. No pictures. Post text. You did not answer my question. It is unclear what you are doing. No context.

Comment: check it my answer

Comment: NO PICTURES! Post text. And first explain what you want and are doing.

Answer (score 1):

I spend my whole day but I found where is the issue.

First I suggests check all dependencies. which are third party library check his verison code.

I'm using this library when I check this lib on github repo his version 1.4@aar
by mistake I'm update with +1

> implementation 'me.gujun.android.taggroup:library:1.5@aar'